# Custom CSS for Multiple DropDown

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have Multiple-DropDown and it has no CSS. I want to apply CSS on it without bootstrap.

I want to apply Custom CSS on it.

[Screenshoot of my DropDown](https://www.screencast.com/t/Q8rrbVOP)

I want right-check in DropDown menu like Bootstrap but Without Bootstrap.

[Like this type of Dropdown (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nb4k.png)

**HTML CODE**

```
   <select id="Job_Type" name="type" multiple>
     <option>All Job Types</option>
     <option value="Permanent">Permanent</option>
     <option value="Contract">Contract</option>
     <option value="Part-Time">Part-Time</option>
    </select>
```

Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried anything to get the desired UI?

Comment: Yes. but not working .its conflict in my another design. That why i don't use bootstrap.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27547021/6808043

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Checkbox inside Select Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714705/how-to-use-checkbox-inside-select-option)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create checkbox inside dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206919/how-to-create-checkbox-inside-dropdown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try  this**

> reference is https://codepen.io/elmahdim/pen/hlmri

```js
/*
 Dropdown with Multiple checkbox select with jQuery - May 27, 2013
 (c) 2013 @ElmahdiMahmoud
 license: https://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*/

$(".dropdown dt a").on('click', function() {
  $(".dropdown dd ul").slideToggle('fast');
});

$(".dropdown dd ul li a").on('click', function() {
  $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
});

function getSelectedValue(id) {
  return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
}

$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
  var $clicked = $(e.target);
  if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown")) $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
});

$('.mutliSelect input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {

  var title = $(this).closest('.mutliSelect').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),
    title = $(this).val() + ",";

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
    $('.multiSel').append(html);
    $(".hida").hide();
  } else {
    $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
    var ret = $(".hida");
    $('.dropdown dt a').append(ret);

  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font: normal 14px/100% "Andale Mono", AndaleMono, monospace;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #374954;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

a {
  color: #fff;
}

.dropdown dd,
.dropdown dt {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.dropdown ul {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
}

.dropdown dd {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown a,
.dropdown a:visited {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.dropdown dt a {
  background-color: #4F6877;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 20px 5px 10px;
  min-height: 25px;
  line-height: 24px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0;
  width: 272px;
}

.dropdown dt a span,
.multiSel span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 3px 2px 0;
}

.dropdown dd ul {
  background-color: #4F6877;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 2px 15px 2px 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  width: 280px;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.dropdown span.value {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown dd ul li a {
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown dd ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

button {
  background-color: #6BBE92;
  width: 302px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="dropdown"> 
  
    <dt>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="hida">Select</span>    
      <p class="multiSel"></p>  
    </a>
    </dt>
  
    <dd>
        <div class="mutliSelect">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Apple" />Apple</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Blackberry" />Blackberry</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="HTC" />HTC</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Sony Ericson" />Sony Ericson</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Motorola" />Motorola</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Nokia" />Nokia</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </dd>
  <button>Filter</button>
</dl>
```