# Need help to modify custom dropdown and change its value

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have ceated a custom dropdown like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zs9iZ.png)

Now on click on listed options, main value should change and a label should float top of it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKBMp.png)

```js
$(".custom-dropdown-main").click(function(){ 
  $(".custom-dropdown").toggle(); 
});
```

```css
.create-new-budget-value-date {
    margin: 30px 0 10px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #d8d9dc;
    position: relative;
}

.create-new-budget-value-date:before {
    content: "";
    background: url(../images/up-arrow.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -14px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 22px;
    height: 14px;
}

.new-budget-value-select {
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #d8d9dc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    min-height: 45px;
}

.new-budget-value-select .custom-dropdown-main {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 10px
}

.new-budget-value-select .custom-dropdown-main .glyphicon-menu-down {
    float: right;
}

.new-budget-value-select .custom-dropdown {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.new-budget-value-select .custom-dropdown .dropdown-item {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 2px;
}

.new-budget-value-select a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.new-budget-value-select .custom-dropdown .dropdown-item:hover {
    background: #e6e6e6;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="new-budget-value-select">
   <a class="custom-dropdown-main" href="#" id="custom-select">
   Budget <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span></a>
   <div class="custom-dropdown" style="display: none;">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom CSS for Multiple DropDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51491432/custom-css-for-multiple-dropdown)

Comment: It should work like default Select dropdown, once we click on the dropdown value, main value should change.

Comment: @Mukesh, pls insert here your css and jquery that you have.

Comment: jquery: 
$(".custom-dropdown-main").click(function(){
    $(".custom-dropdown").toggle();
  });

Comment: @Mukesh, Do you want multiple additions, or just one value?

Comment: @s. Kuznetsov - one value whichever is clicked. Once clicked main value should be changed and dropdown should be closed. thank

Comment: @Mukesh, I have given a solution. Check, pls.

Comment: @s.Kuznetsov - it has solved 90% of issue, thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Mukesh, Maybe I can help solve the remaining 10%? lol

Comment: @s. kuznetsov - Sure, actually i want a default value in the dropdown which should remain unchange and once we click on any other value, that default value should move up like a label.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov - Please refer one of the screenshot in the post. thanks

Comment: @Mukesh, I did. Check my answer, pls.

Comment: @s. Kuznetsov - I checked but its not working :(

Comment: @s. Kuznetsov - now its working. thanks mate!!!

Comment: yup thank you so much @s. Kuznetsov!!

Comment: @Mukesh, always glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".custom-dropdown-main").click(function(){ 
  $(".custom-dropdown").toggle(); 
});

$(".custom-dropdown .dropdown-item").on('click', function() {
  $(".custom-dropdown-main").text($(this).text());
  $(".custom-dropdown-main").prepend('<span class="label">Budget</span>');
  $(".custom-dropdown").hide();      
});
```

```css
.create-new-budget-value-date {
    margin: 30px 0 10px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #d8d9dc;
    position: relative;
}

.create-new-budget-value-date:before {
    content: "";
    background: url(../images/up-arrow.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -14px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 22px;
    height: 14px;
}

.new-budget-value-select {
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #d8d9dc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    min-height: 45px;
}

.new-budget-value-select .custom-dropdown-main {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 10px
}

.new-budget-value-select .custom-dropdown-main .glyphicon-menu-down {
    float: right;
}

.new-budget-value-select .custom-dropdown {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.new-budget-value-select .custom-dropdown .dropdown-item {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 2px;
}

.new-budget-value-select a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.new-budget-value-select .custom-dropdown .dropdown-item:hover {
    background: #e6e6e6;
    color: #000;
}

.label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="new-budget-value-select">
   <a class="custom-dropdown-main" href="#" id="custom-select">
   Budget <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span></a>
   <div class="custom-dropdown" style="display: none;">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
   </div>
</div>
```