# How to generate a dropdown with checkboxes using javascript only

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox, dropdown

Is there a possibility to generate a dropdown with checkboxes?

I have only seen javascript code that generates only a dropdown.

This is the script what I have written:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test() {
            var d = new Date();
            var currentYear = d.getFullYear();
            var currentMonth = d.getMonth();
            var yroptions = "<option value='0'>select</option>";

            for(var i = currentYear; i < currentYear + 5; i++)
            {
                yroptions += "<option value='"+i+"'>"+i+"</option>";
            }
            document.getElementById('ccexpy').innerHTML = yroptions;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="test()">

<form method="post" action="url to script">
    <label for="ccexpy">Year</label>
    <select id="ccexpy">

    </select>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show what you've already tried, and provide code samples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create checkbox inside dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206919/how-to-create-checkbox-inside-dropdown)