# How to select checkboxes from the dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

```css
  .gradesub-filter{
    width: 299px;
    height: 370px;
    margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
  .form-filter-shade{
    padding: 16px 0px 9px 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #F0F0F0;
  }
    .checkbox-alignment-form-filter{
    padding-left: 21px;
    padding-top: 18px;
  }
```

```html
    <div class="gradesub-filter">
    <div class="form-filter-shade">Gradesort</div>
    <div class="checkbox-alignment-form-filter">
        <input type="checkbox" id="three" class="vh-product" checked="checked" />
        <label class="productlist-specific" for="three"> 2011</label> 
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-alignment-form-filter2">
        <input type="checkbox" id="four" class="vh-product" checked="checked" />
        <label class="productlist-specific" for="four">2012</label> 
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-alignment-form-filter3">
        <input type="checkbox" id="five" class="vh-product" checked="checked" />
        <label class="productlist-specific" for="five">2013</label> 
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-alignment-form-filter4">
        <input type="checkbox" id="six" class="vh-product" checked="checked" />
        <label class="productlist-specific" for="six">2014</label> 
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-alignment-form-filter5">
        <input type="checkbox" id="seven" class="vh-product" checked="checked" />
        <label class="productlist-specific" for="seven">2015</label> 
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-alignment-form-filter">
        <input type="checkbox" id="eight" class="vh-product" checked="checked" />
        <label class="productlist-specific" for="eight">2016</label> 
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-alignment-form-filter7">
        <input type="checkbox" id="nine" class="vh-product" checked="checked" />
        <label class="productlist-specific" for="nine">2017</label> 
    </div>
      </div>
```

How to make checkboxes to select from a dropdown. basically i have checkbox and need to select checkboxes from the dropdown,

not sure, how to add dropdown for the checkboxes and when user click on dropdown , then checkbox should scroll down

Comment: hello, you can do this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19207528/12415287). Hope this helps.

Comment: What dropdown..?

Comment: @TJ I have some checkboxes, where initially i am able to see them now(without dropdown), But want checkboxes to see from the dropdown when user clicked on.