# Column Based Dropdown Checkbox-list Filtering in HTML Table (Excel Like)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, dropdownchecklist

I have an HTML Table where I display various values, I need to filter by column in this table.
I want to list values ​​in column as checkbox in dropdown like in excel but I'm not used to JavaScript or jQuery. Here is my view;

```
@using Company.Models
@model IList<VWStockListModel>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Active Stock List";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/LeftBarV1.cshtml";
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">             
                <div class="card-body">
                    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    Warehouse Code
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="myInput0" onkeyup="myFunction(0)" placeholder="Search">
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    First Warehouse
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="myInput1" onkeyup="myFunction(1)" placeholder="Search">
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Stock Name
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="myInput2" onkeyup="myFunction(2)" placeholder="Search">
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Quality
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="myInput3" onkeyup="myFunction(3)" placeholder="Search">
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Thickness
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="myInput4" onkeyup="myFunction(4)" placeholder="Search">
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Width
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="myInput5" onkeyup="myFunction(5)" placeholder="Search">
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Height
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="myInput6" onkeyup="myFunction(6)" placeholder="Search">
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Tonnage
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="myInput7" onkeyup="myFunction(7)" placeholder="Search">
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Ord Tonnage
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="myInput8" onkeyup="myFunction(8)" placeholder="Search">
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Net Tonnage
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="myInput9" onkeyup="myFunction(9)" placeholder="Search">
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Work Order Tonnage
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="myInput10" onkeyup="myFunction(10)" placeholder="Search">
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Origin
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="myInput11" onkeyup="myFunction(11)" placeholder="Search">
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Roll No
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="myInput12" onkeyup="myFunction(12)" placeholder="Search">
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Price
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="myInput13" onkeyup="myFunction(13)" placeholder="Search">
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Description
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="myInput14" onkeyup="myFunction(14)" placeholder="Search">
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Op End Time
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="myInput15" onkeyup="myFunction(15)" placeholder="Search">
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Group Code
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="myInput16" onkeyup="myFunction(16)" placeholder="Search">
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var x in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@x.WarehouseCode</td>
                                <td>@x.FirstWarehouse</td>
                                <td>@x.StockName.Replace('Ý', 'İ').Replace('Þ', 'Ş').Replace('Ð', 'Ğ')</td>
                                <td>@x.Quality</td>
                                <td>@x.Thickness.ToString("N2")</td>
                                <td>@x.Width.ToString("N0")</td>
                                <td>@x.Height.ToString("N0")</td>
                                <td>@x.Tonnage.ToString("N0")</td>
                                <td>@x.OrdTonnage.ToString("N0")</td>
                                <td>@x.NetTonnage.ToString("N0")</td>
                                <td>@x.WorkOrdTonnage.ToString("N0")</td>
                                <td>@x.Origin</td>
                                <td>@x.RollNo</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">@x.Price.ToString("N2")</td>
                                <td>@x.Description</td>
                                <td>@x.OpEndTime</td>
                                <td>@x.GroupCode</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
```

It works with searching right now.

VWStockListModel;

```
public class VWSacStokListModel
    {
        public string StokName { get; set; }
        public string GroupCode { get; set; }
        public int WarehouseCode { get; set; }
        public int FirstWarehouse { get; set; }
        public string RollNo { get; set; }
        public string Origin { get; set; }
        public string Quality { get; set; }
        public decimal Thickness { get; set; }
        public decimal Width { get; set; }
        public decimal Height { get; set; }
        public decimal Tonnage { get; set; }
        public decimal OrdTonnage { get; set; }
        public decimal WorkOrdTonnage { get; set; }
        public string OpEndTime { get; set; }
        public string Descrpition { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public decimal NetTonnage{ get; set; }

    }
```

Also here is the example of it from Excel;
[Excel Filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ax32.png)

Comment: What column do you want to be a checkbox? Share your `VWStockListModel` model.

Comment: I added the model. Basically all columns.

Comment: You want to check which columns should be visible, is that it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what research you've done into solving this problem yourself. For instance, a simple search on "checkbox in dropdown" found [How to create checkbox inside dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19206919/215552)

Comment: @iamdlm No sorry I think I explained it wrong, I want to filter the datas in table by selecting checkboxes for each columns.